# Same size of Container View and its child view

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, autolayout, interface-builder

I have an iOS project where I have my main view Controller, `A`, and another ViewController `B`. `B` is embedded in `A` as a child view controller. The whole thing is set up in Interface Builder using a Container View.

[image: Setup Logic]

Now, `B` has some logic where it reacts to pan gestures to resize its view. This all works fine, the problem is that the Container View always stays the same size and does not resize with `B`'s root view. I want the Container View's size to stay in sync with the root view of `B`.

What is the best approach for this? Is there any way to set this up in Interface Builder? The only feasible solution I found so far was to create a `BDelegate`, which `A` listens to and then resizes the Container View. Is there an easier way to achieve this?

thanks

Comment: The idea of "container view" is to "auto-load" a child view controller, and display its view as a subview of the container. So, as you've seen, changing the size of the connected "child" view does not change the container. You can certainly do it via code, but if you're looking for an auto-layout only option, you will probably be better off *not* using container view, and just making `B` a subview to begin with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to your answers, I got pointed in the right direction - specifically, that this is not possible the way I thought it was.

**There is no way to have constraints between the views of a parent view controller and a child view controller - neither in IB, nor in code**

As far as I can see, there are two ways to solve this:

1. Don't use a second UIViewController. Make the root view of your child view controller an actual subview of yourself, and just have a single UIViewController.
2. Do not use auto layout. Manage the frame of your child view controller's view manually, and have delegate callbacks back to your parent view controller where necessary. In those delegate callbacks, your parent view controller can react to size changes of the child view controller's view.

Comment: As a general rule, Discard solution #2... auto-layout and constraints are a perfectly good way to manage different screen sizes and orientations. Occasionally you might want to use code to set / change specific constraint values, but you'd still be using auto-layout.

Answer (score -1):

equalHeight and equalWidth constraints should solve your problem

Comment: Sorry, I probably should have clarified: IB does not allow constraints between a Container View and its child. At least I couldn't figure out a way to do it.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/flk2ik
just right drag from the view to its container u ll find it

Comment: The problem is that the child view does not appear in the same tree as the container view: http://imgur.com/a/DAfnT . Here, the top view controller is `A` and the bottom view controller is `B`, and I want `Timeline Container` and `Visual Effect View` to sync their sizes

Comment: I see! well i believe you can only accomplish this by code then